# How to enable exec() in server?

Tags: php, exec

I dont know how to enable exec in server.Please help me

Comment: I don't think you do need to enable it? What error message are you getting (if any)? What string are you passing to it? Are you running in safe mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's your the server or it's hosted ?
anyway the configuration is into the php.ini, you can understand if is disabled by using this code:

```
<?php
function exec_enabled() {
  $disabled = explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions'));
  return !in_array('exec', $disabled);
}
?>
```